# Bug in Swift If statement

Tags: swift, debugging, if-statement, uitextfield

I have set 4 UITextFields and one UIButton. This is working as a register page were the user provides data such as Username, email, password, etc. So only and only where all the UItextfields are NOT empty the register button will be enable so the user can tap inside and go to the next UIView. Everything is working fine but I notice a little bug that it's getting into my last nerve XD.

If the user fill all the UItextFields with all nthe information required but for some reason backspace into one of them until the field is empty and then tap into the register button the Signup will be succesfull even though there was a empty field. Please I have been almost a week trying to figure this out.

The way I seted up the UIbotton:

```
private let registerButton : UIButton = {
    let button = UIButton(type: .system)
    button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    button.setTitle("Registrar", for: .normal)
    button.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
    button.layer.cornerRadius = 5
    button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 14)
    button.setTitleColor(.black, for: .normal)
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleSignUp), for: .touchUpInside)
    button.isEnabled = true
    return button
}()
```

The block code in charge of validating if all the fields are already being filled by the user.

```
@objc private func handleSignUp () {
    let userName = userNameTexField.text
    let email = emailTextField.text
    let password = passwordTextField.text
    let confirmPassword = confirmPasswordField.text
    let birthDate = birthDateTextField.text

    if userName?.isEmpty ?? true && email?.isEmpty ?? true && password?.isEmpty ?? true && confirmPassword?.isEmpty ?? true && birthDate?.isEmpty ?? true {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: "Youmust fill all the fields with all the required infotmation to signup", preferredStyle: .alert)
        let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
        alert.addAction(okAction)
        present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }else {
        emailTextField.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
        passwordTextField.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
        confirmPasswordField.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
        birthDateTextField.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToHome", sender: nil)
        print("LogIn succesful!")
        print (userAge)
    }
}
```

I expect to fix this bugg so when the user, for some reason, erase one of the fields the alert pops up again telling the user to fill all the fills to sign up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are requiring all the fields to be empty to trigger your alert. What you need is to know that one of them is empty. Try changing the `&&` to `||`.

```
if userName?.isEmpty ?? true || email?.isEmpty ?? true || password?.isEmpty ?? true || confirmPassword?.isEmpty ?? true || birthDate?.isEmpty ?? true
```

Comment: OMG thank you very much!!!! this works fine. And lots of thanks to the other people who took the time to answer as well. Very thankful!

Answer (score 1):

You should use `||` in your `if` instead of `&&` because you want to show alert when at least one of those field is empty

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the operator or instead of and because you have a check for any empty text field:

```
@objc private func handleSignUp () {

    if textField1.text!.isEmpty || textField2.text!.isEmpty || textField3.text!.isEmpty || textField4.text!.isEmpty || textField5.text!.isEmpty {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: "Youmust fill all the fields with all the required infotmation to signup", preferredStyle: .alert)
        let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
        alert.addAction(okAction)
        present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }else {
        textField2.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
        textField3.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
        textField4.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
        textField5.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToHome", sender: nil)
        print("LogIn succesful!")
        print ("userAge")

    }
}
```